# Why can't I scroll to the bottom of my div?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, socket.io, vuejs3, scrolltop

so basicaly, i'm doing a chat in vuejs + socket.io
and I want that every time a message is sent, received, or when you come to the site, you arrive directly to the bottom of the page, where the latest message is

I've done a function that fires on the onMounted hook, when I retrieve the data, and on the socket.on('message') :

```js
        const scrollToLatest = () => {
            let container = document.getElementById("messages")
            console.log("scrolltop",container.scrollTop)
            console.log("scrollheight",container.scrollHeight)
            container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
            console.log("scrolltop after", container.scrollTop)
        }
```

[Here are what the console.log returns :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6db0C.png)

(if you can't load the image :)

```
scrolltop 0
scrollheight 5594
scrolltop after 0
```

I've tried to use `window.scrollTo(0, container.scrollHeight)` but it doesn't work either

I hope that someone will be able to help me, I've searched a lot on this issue, but I wasn't able to make it work properly

Answer (score 0):

pass a custom class to your `div` in your `<template>` first:

```
<div :class="`messages`">
</div>
```

and then get the position of the `div` as a number:

```
getPositionOfElement() {
  return (document.getElementsByClassName("messages").getBoundingClientRect().top - window.innerHeight);
}
```

This would be the method for scrolling to the position where your `div` is located - adapt it to your needs as described in the [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo):

```
smoothScroll(vertPos) {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: vertPos,
    left: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

combine both methods like this from the place where you need to perform the scrolling - calling this either from another method or directly from the template...

```
this.smoothScroll(this.getPositionOfElement());
```

Please let me know if this works for you.